# jpql select object from table based on some property from another table?

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jpa, jpql

I am new to jpql.
I have two mySql tables.
Table advert: with columns:

> id, name, description, phone, category etc..

And table advert_property with following columns:

```
id          int 11
advert_id   int 11  
name        varchar 255 
value       varchar 255     
descr       varchar 255
```

My goal is to choose object from table `advert` which has a property `category = "flats"` written in table `advert` property with name `number_rooms = "234"` written in table `advert_property`.

I'm a little bit confused with jpql syntaxis i came to this solution:

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT ap FROM AdvertProperty as ap, Advert as a "  
 + " where a.category= 'flats' and ap.advertId = a.id and ap.name='number_rooms' ");

List<Advert> ads = q.getResultList();
```

But it doesn't work as i needed..

Please suggest,
Thanks

Advert entity :

```
public class Advert implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 255)
private String title;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
private String content;
private Integer price;
@Size(max = 255)
@Column(name = "contact_person")
private String contactPerson;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Size(max = 255)
private String email;
// @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Size(max = 255)
private String phone;
@Column(name = "address_id")
private Integer addressId;
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Integer categoryId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "company_type")
private boolean companyType;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
private boolean approved;
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer userId;
@Column(name = "who_can_watch")
private Integer whoCanWatch;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "creation_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationDate;
@Size(max = 255)
private String razdel;

public Advert() {
}

public Advert(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

AdvertProperty Entity:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "advert_property")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findByAdvertId", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a WHERE a.advertId = :advertId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a WHERE a.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findByValue", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a WHERE a.value = :value"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertProperty.findByDescr", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertProperty a WHERE a.descr = :descr")})
public class AdvertProperty implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "advert_id")
    private Integer advertId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String value;
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String descr;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Since you already have a foreign key from `advert_property` to `advert`, you can model your entities accordingly

In **Advert** entity

```
...
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "advert")
private AdvertProperty property;
// or this, in case it is one to many
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "advert")
private List<AdvertProperty> properties;
...
```

In **AdvertProperty** entity

```
@ManyToOne // or @OneToOne
@JoinColumn("advert_id")
private Advert advert;
```

In case it is `@OneToMany`, the query would look like this

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Advert a join a.properties p where a.category = 'flats' and p.name='number_rooms' ");
```

In case it is `@OneToOne`, the query would look like this

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Advert a where a.category = 'flats' and a.property.name='number_rooms' ");
```

Comment: Nope, my properties mostly in another table, so a.property.name - it won't chose anything, i don't use foreign keys

Comment: Is there a relation between two entities? Could you post entities in your question? If there is a relation (and there could be, based on `advert_property.advert_id`), and `Advert` has a relation like `AdvertProperty property;`, this query would work.

Comment: yes, advert_property has column advert_id which points to advert. See upd question for entitites=)

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you implemented your entities:

```
SELECT a FROM Advert a JOIN a.properties ap where a.category = 'flats' and ap.name='number_rooms'
```

or

```
SELECT a FROM AdvertPropery ap JOIN ap.advert where a.category = 'flats' and ap.name='number_rooms'
```

However post your entities to have an exact answer.

---

That's not how JPA is supposed to do a mapping, you should use relational annotations (@OneToMany, @ManyToOne, ...) and mapping annotations (@JoinColumn, @JoinTable, ...)

without relations (and indexes!!) the only query you can do is similar to what you've just done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap FROM AdvertProperty ap, Advert a where a.category= 'flats' and ap.advertId = a.id and ap.name='number_rooms'
```

nevertheless this query is not optimized (no indexes...) and has a very bad performace.